# Is there a way to enable/disable specific JS script execution for specific websites?

Tags: javascript

If I have JS script on several different websites, is it possible to enable or disable script execution for specific sites? If this isn't possible, other suggestions for implementation are welcome.

Here's the application:
I have a script tag with my JS source link that site owners can put on their website to enable interaction with my service. However, I would like to be able to enable/disable the service for specific sites so as not to deploy it until they are ready.

note: The script tag also includes site verification information so it gets put on their site before they are ready to deploy. This saves the step of putting in a site verification tag and then going back and putting in the script.

Comment: If you don't need that javaScript on the page, why not remove it?

Comment: The site that serves up your script content is free to interpret the HTTP request (and accompanying information) any way it wants, including returning nothing if that makes sense.

Comment: Have you looked at how Google does it with keys?

Comment: What do you mean by "execution"? If I include this on my site: `function alertMe(name) { alert(name); }`, but I never call `alertMe`, it will not "execute".

Comment: what is your website/server side technology?

Answer (score 0):

You would want them to put your .ashx handler on your website, then make that return the javascript.

Follow tutorial for ashx page if you are unsure how to http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ASP/Generic_Handlers_(ASHX_Files).html

in the `processrequest()` function:

- Check to see if they have it enabled you can use the querystring to see which website it is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx in the code below there is `?yourwebsitedomain=customersdomain` so you would query for `"yourwebsitedomain"` and you would get `"customersdomain"`
- If they do then Get the bytes of your file using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(filename))`
- and write the results to the output

  ```
  context.Response.OutputStream.Write(FileBytes, 0, FileBytes.Length);
  context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
  ```

Your Customers Website:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    var c = document.createElement('script');
    c.type = 'text/javascript'; c.async = true;
    c.src = "http://yourdomane/yourhandler.ashx?yourwebsitedomain=customersdomain";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(c,s);
  })();
</script>
```

Hope this helps.